# Why background-image is not displayed?

Tags: html, css

I create css class with background-image property and i put it to HTML but, the image is not displayed:

Here is css class:

```
.showLayers{
    background-image: url("http://localhost/mapserver2017/stdicons/GeomindIcons/showLayers.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.miniToolbarContant{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

Here is HTML element:

```
 <button type="button" class="button_air-medium">
              <img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant showLayers"/></button>
```

But the image is never showed.

while if I change the HTML above like that:

```
<button type="button" class="button_air-medium">
                  <img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant" src="../stdicons/GeomindIcons/showLayers.png"/></button>
```

Everything works fine.

Any idea why image is not displayed?

What I do wrong?

Comment: Why would you use an `img` to display a _background_ image? Stop that nonsense first.

Comment: A nonexistant image has a size of 0, so it would be invisible unless you specify dimensions.

Comment: are you working on live site or localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `background-size`

```
.showLayers{
    background-image: url("http://localhost/mapserver2017/stdicons/GeomindIcons/showLayers.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for post.I get rectangle wrapping the image. any idea how can i remove it?

Comment: you should use `<a>` instead `<a href="javascirpt:;"><img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant" src="image.png"/></a>`

Comment: You mean instead button I shoud use <a>?

Answer (score 0):

Use background-image on button not on its child - img

Answer (score 0):

Just change in css `.showLayers` to `#showLayers`

Because you gave styling to a class called showLayers in CSS and then in HTML you were calling an ID called showLayers which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Its beacuse of your invalid file location.
On your first img tag you didn't add file location while in the second you did. In case you don't know suppose that we have four directory (One, Two, Three,Four), (Three inside Two, Two inside One, Four inside One)
Like:

```
One
|_Two
| |_Three   
|_Four
```

So when you are inside Three you can't access directory One or Two or Four.
In order to access directory One you need to use `../../file_name` here `../` used to access parent of current working directory.